# SQL Conditional Join Query

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, join

Consider 3 tables :

Table1

```
id(pkey) text 
col1  text
```

Example (Table1)

```
id col1
1  value1
2  value2
```

Table2

```
id(pkey) text 
name  text
```

Example (Table2)

```
id name
1  name1
2  name2
3  name3
```

Table3

```
table1_id text 
table2_id text
```

Example (Table3)

```
table1_id table2_id
1          1
2          1
2          2
```

How do you use joins to select entries(unique) from table 1 such that :

1. Table1.id == Table3.table1_id
2. Table2.id == Table3.table2_id
3. All of Table2.name that are linked to that table1 entry exactly match a given set of strings.

Sample expected :
If the given search set is : ['name1', 'name2']; return all entries from table1 linked to ALL the entries from table3 which have name as 'name1' or 'name2'.

In the considered example, sample valid response :

```
id col1
2  value2
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are really used.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hi EI Cid , I have checked the below query at SQL server and its working fine for me , please let me know if still have the problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff addressed your comment.

Comment: @AjeetVerma your query does not look correct. Maybe the example might help ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select t3.table1_id
from table3 t3 join
     table2 t2
     on t3.table2_id = t2.id
group by t3.table1_id
having sum( case when t2.name in (?, ?, ?) then 1 else 0 end) = count(*) and
       count(*) = 3;  -- number of elements
```

Note:  This assumes that `table3` has no duplicates, which is normally the case.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below SQL query for your problem , I have tried it at my end it working for me .

```
SELECT t1.id
    ,t1.col1
FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN Table3 AS t3 ON t1.id = t3.table1_id
INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t3.table2_id
WHERE t2.name = t1.col1
```

Please check snapshot for the result of this query for better understanding.

[image]